# The user drop down menu shows a wrong reputation change

Tags: support, user-interface, reputation

My drop down menu shows a change in my reputation of +1, but when click on the reputation link, the page I am taken to shows a different reputation change.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

The last reputation change is from yesterday; there is not reputation change for today. In any case, I don't see any +1 changes. The reputation change show in the latter screenshot is ordered by time.

I also made a little experiment, and I have got the following.

[image: screenshot]

The reputation change still doesn't show any changes for today, and my reputation as for this moment is still 18,709.

Comment: Did you revert a downvote?  That would cause a +1 gain, but might now show up in your rep feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reputation dropdown shows a *net* change for the day, so things like reverting a downvote or a post being deleted that you downvoted would change your rep, but not show in *your* reputation report.

Over time as deletions and such happen, the report vs actual may becomes a little skewed, you can sync your history at any time by performing a recalc.  You can do so at the bottom of: https://english.stackexchange.com/reputation

Comment: What I did, between the situation shown in the first screenshot and the situation shown in the second screenshot, was to remove a down-vote from a post, and then re-add it. The system noticed the down-vote has not been removed (the reputation didn't change), it didn't add a new entry in the reputation table, but it did remove the entry about the down-vote done the previous day. In other words, the system was able to update the shown data in a way, but not in the other way.